# What are the various ways to achieve IOC in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

What are the various ways to Achieve IOC in Spring? Can anyone throw me an article or example of usage of IOC and various ways to achieve IOC.

What are other concepts of Spring framework which makes it so popular and which i should know.

Comment: Have you read [Chapter 3. The IoC container](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html) in the Spring documentation?

Comment: Read the documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html. Surprinsingly, it starts with an overview and has a chapter on IOC.

Comment: It is achieved using dependency injection, namely field, setter or constructor injection. What more do you want?

Comment: @Tomasz or Lookup Method Injection :-)

Answer (score 2):

The complete Reference can be found at:

> [Spring 3.x Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/) > [3. The IoC Container](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html)